# Trying to run a python script every hour for 24 hours in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, file, scheduled-tasks

Here's what I'm trying to do: I'd like to run the following function every hour for 24 hours. This function collects data from an api, appends values to a dictionary and saves it as a json file for later use. The code I'm running works ok but it is not elegant as I have to KeyboardInterrupt to stop it. I'd like for the script to stop running after 24hrs and to print at each hour: `print('data successfully collected at ' + time.ctime()`

```
def weather_collect():
    url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={}&lon={}&appid={}&units=metric'
    response = requests.get(url.format(lat,lon, api_key))
    r = response.json()
    data['temperature'].append(r['main']['temp'])
    data['humidity'].append(r['main']['humidity'])
    data['pressure'].append(r['main']['pressure'])
    data['visibility'].append(r['visibility'])
    data['wind_speed'].append(r['wind']['speed'])
    data['time'].append(time.ctime())
    with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data))
    return data

schedule.every(1).hour.do(weather_collect)
while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```py
schedule.every(1).hour.do(weather_collect)
while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Put this one:

```py
for i in range(25):
    weather_collect()
    print('data successfully collected at ' + time.ctime())
    sleep(3600) # sleep one hour
exit()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to add a counter you increment by 1 every time the loop executes.
And break the "while 1" loop on the 24th iteration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).